# Matlab: Plot3 not showing the 3rd axis

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot, 4d

All the three variables I am using to plot are matrix of size `1x1x100`. I am using this code line to plot:

```
hold on; 
for i=1:100
    plot3(R_L(:,:,i),N_Pc(:,:,i),CO2_molefraction_top_of_window(:,:,i),'o');
    xlabel('R_L');
    ylabel('N_P_c');
    zlabel('CO_2')
end
```

However, I am not getting the third axis, and hence the third variable `CO2_molefraction_top_of_window` on the plot. May I know where am I wrong?

Besides the above question, but on the same subject, I want to know if there is any option where I can plot 4 dimensional plot just like the 3 dimensional plot which can be drawn using `plot3`?

Comment: What does a 4D plot look like when viewed on a 2D screen ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a note --- you only need to do the `xlabel` `ylabel` `zlabel` commands once (outside the loop).

Also:

- is there any reason your matrices are `1x1x100` instead of just `100x1` or `1x100`?
  Because if you reshape them to 2D you can just do the plotting in one hit.
- What do you mean by "missing third axis"? When I run your code (or as close as I can get, since you didn't provide a reproducible example), I *do* get a 3rd axis:

.

```
X = rand(1,1,100); % 1x1x100 X matrix
Y = rand(1,1,100); % 1x1x100 Y matrix
Z = rand(1,1,100); % 1x1x100 Z matrix
% Now, we could do a for loop and plot X(:,:,i), Y(:,:,i), Z(:,:,i),
% OR we can just convert the matrix to a vector (since it's 1x1x100 anyway)
%    and do the plotting in one go using 'squeeze' (see 'help squeeze').
%    squeeze(X) converts it from 1x1x100 (3D matrix) to 100x1 (vector):
plot3(squeeze(X),squeeze(Y),squeeze(Z),'o')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
zlabel('z')
```

This gives the following, in which you can clearly see three axes:
[image]

If it's the gridlines that you want to make the graph look "more 3D", then try `grid on`  (which is in the examples in the Matlab help file for `plot3`, try `help plot3` from the Matlab prompt):

```
grid on
```

[image]

You will have to clarify "missing third axis" a bit more.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow when I was plotting with matrix size `1x1x100` I was not getting the 3rd axis. But, `squeeze` is a nice function and the 3rd axis is appearing as well. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, and those labels inside the loop were my mistake. Didn't look at them being inside the loop.

Answer (score 4):

So I had the same problem when using `plot3`. For some reason, using the `hold on` command "flattens" the plot. I'm not sure why, but I suspect it has something to do with the operation `hold on` performs on the plot.
Edit: To clarify, the 3d plot is still there, but the perspective has been forced to change. If you use the "rotate 3D" tool (the one with an arrow around a cube), you can see the graph is 3d, the default perspective is just straight on so only two axes are visible and it appears flat.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar problem and as @Drofdarb's the `hold on` seems to flatten out one axis. Here is a snippet of my code, hope this helps.

```
for iter = 1:num_iters:
    % hold on;
    grid on;
    plot3(tita0,tita1, num_iters,'o')
    title('Tita0, Tita1')
    xlabel('Tita0')
    ylabel('Tita1')
    zlabel('Iterations')
    hold on;            % <---- Place here
    drawnow   
end
```

[image]

---

As opposed to:

```
for iter = 1:num_iters:
    grid on;
    hold on;          % <---- Not here
    plot3(tita0,tita1, num_iters,'o')
    title('Tita0, Tita1')
    xlabel('Tita0')
    ylabel('Tita1')
    zlabel('Iterations')
    % hold on;
    drawnow   
end
```

[image]